# Passing unique pointer to template function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, unique-ptr

I'm trying to figure out how exactly the `unique_ptr` type plays with templates in C++11, and am not having much luck: Specifically, I'm trying to make a template function which inserts a `unique_ptr` value for a given unique key in a given map if there is not already a value for the key in the map, and moves ownership of the value pointed to by the `unique_ptr` to the value in the map; If the key is already present, a runtime error is thrown.

Now, moving the value of a `unique_ptr` is quite straightforward if you don't have to pass it to a function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unordered_map<char, unique_ptr<int> > testMap;

    char key1 = 'A';
    unique_ptr<int> val1(new int(1));
    testMap[key1] = move(val1);

    // Print the results
    cout << "testMap[" << key1 << "] = " << *testMap[key1] << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

## Non-template function

Passing the `unique_ptr` to a function is a bit more complicated:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

void moveValueForUniqueKey(unordered_map<char, unique_ptr<int> >& targetMap, char key, unique_ptr<int> value) throw(char)
{
    // Check if the key is already in the map
    auto it = targetMap.find(key);
    if (it != targetMap.end())
    {
        throw key;
    }
    else
    {
        targetMap[key] = move(value);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unordered_map<char, unique_ptr<int> > testMap;
    char key1 = 'A';
    unique_ptr<int> val1(new int(1));

    // Try inserting the first key-value pair
    try
    {
        moveValueForUniqueKey(testMap, key1, move(val1));
    }
    catch (char& duplicateKey)
    {
        cerr << "Key '" << duplicateKey << "' already in map." << endl;
    }

    // Print the key-value pairs
    for (pair<const char, unique_ptr<int> >& entry : testMap)
    {
        cout << "testMap['" << entry.first << "'] = " << *entry.second << endl;
    }

    unique_ptr<int> val2(new int(2));

    // Try inserting the key again
    try
    {
        moveValueForUniqueKey(testMap, key1, move(val2));
    }
    catch (char& duplicateKey)
    {
        cerr << "Key '" << duplicateKey << "' already in map." << endl;
    }

    // Print the key-value pairs again
    for (pair<const char, unique_ptr<int> >& entry : testMap)
    {
        cout << "testMap['" << entry.first << "'] = " << *entry.second << endl;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

This code outputs:

```
testMap['A'] = 1
Key 'A' already in map.
testMap['A'] = 1
```

## Function template

Now, when I try to make a template of this function, replacing the previous declaration/implementation of `moveValueForUniqueKey(...)` with:

```
template<typename K, typename V, typename M>
void moveValueForUniqueKey(M targetMap, K key, unique_ptr<V> value) throw(char)
{
    // Check if the key is already in the map
    auto it = targetMap.find(key);
    if (it != targetMap.end())
    {
        throw key;
    }
    else
    {
        targetMap[key] = move(value);
    }
}

// Instantiate template function
template
void moveValueForUniqueKey(unordered_map<char, unique_ptr<int> >& targetMap, char key, unique_ptr<int> value) throw(char);
```

I simply get the compiler error `use of deleted function ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = const char, _T2 = std::unique_ptr<int>, std::pair<_T1, _T2> = std::pair<const char, std::unique_ptr<int> >]’`.

What exactly is going on here, and how can you accomplish what I'm trying here (pass `unique_ptr` objects into template functions using move semantics)?

Comment: `remove_reference<unique_ptr<int>&>::type` is redundant...

Comment: I don't understand: Why `remove_reference<unique_ptr<int>&>::type` and not just `unique_ptr<int>`?

Comment: Okay, that's strange: while playing around with it I thought I needed that, but it seems to compile now with just `unique_ptr<int>`...

Comment: Just to note: Changing the type to `unique_ptr<int>` doesn't solve my problem with the function template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this:

```
remove_reference<unique_ptr<int>&>::type
```

Is just equivalent to this:

```
unique_ptr<int>
```

I do not see the need for the `remove_reference` there. To convince yourself, try the following:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>

static_assert(std::is_same<
    remove_reference<unique_ptr<int>&>::type, 
    unique_ptr<int>>::value, "!");
```

And you will see that the assertion does not fire ([*live example*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=82e15dde8c5ca39695eb787c5586ee51-25dabfc2c190f5ef027f31d968947336)).

Most likely the reason for the compiler error you are getting is that you are not using the `typename` disambiguator in your function template:

```
template<typename K, typename V, typename M>
void moveValueForUniqueKey(M targetMap, K key, 
    typename remove_reference<unique_ptr<V>&>::type value) throw(char)
//  ^^^^^^^^
{
    // ...
}
```

But again, there is no reason to use `remove_reference` there:

```
template<typename K, typename V, typename M>
void moveValueForUniqueKey(M targetMap, K key, unique_ptr<V> value) throw(char)
//                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    // ...
}
```

Finally, keep in mind that dynamic exception specifications are deprecated in C++11.

Comment: Oh, and thanks for the heads-up about the exception specifications: Somehow that never got expressed loudly enough for me to take notice.

Answer (score 1):

Well first you would need `typename` since you are obtaining a type through a template argument:

```
template<typename K, typename V, typename M>
void moveValueForUniqueKey(
    M targetMap, K key, typename remove_reference<unique_ptr<V>&>::type value) throw(char)
    //                  ^^^^^^^^
{...}
```

But you don't need the signature `remove_refrence<T&>::type`. Why aren't you just using `T`?

```
template<typename K, typename V, typename M>
void moveValueForUniqueKey(M targetMap, K key, unique_ptr<V> value) throw(char)
{...}
```

`std::unique_ptr` cannot be copied, so you should simply *move* any lvalues into the parameter. For example, you have an invalid line in your main. Change this:

```
moveValueForUniqueKey(testMap, key1, move(val2));
```

to this

```
moveValueForUniqueKey(move(testMap), key1, move(val2));
//                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks; the `remove_reference<T&>::type` nonsense means that I should probably get some sleep now...

Comment: Just to note: `void moveValueForUniqueKey(M targetMap, K key, unique_ptr<V> value) throw(char)` doesn't compile on my machine:

`use of deleted function ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = const char, _T2 = std::unique_ptr<int>, std::pair<_T1, _T2> = std::pair<const char, std::unique_ptr<int> >]`

Comment: Yes: it is used internally by `unordered_map`.

Comment: @errantlinguist `unique_ptr` is not copyable, so somewhere in your code you are doing copy-construction.

Comment: @errantlinguist I found it. The offending line is: `moveValueForUniqueKey(testMap, key1, move(val2));`. You must move the parameter: `moveValueForUniqueKey(move(testMap), key1, move(val2));`

Comment: Yes, hence the attempt to pass `unique_ptr<int>`, `unique_ptr<int>&`, `remove_reference<unique_ptr<V>&>::type` and `remove_reference<unique_ptr<V>&>::type&`, none of which work.

Comment: @errantlinguist You forgot to move the first parameter: `moveValueForUniqueKey(std::move(testMap), key1, std::move(val2));`

Comment: But why, when I pass a reference to an `unordered_map<char, unique_ptr<int> >`, do the map entries get copied??? I'm even more confused now...

Comment: @errantlinguist The map entries do **not** get copied if you pass by reference. I was just assuming that you didn't want to pass by reference since you were using `remove_reference<T&>::type`. If you want you can change the signature in your function to `void moveValueForUniqueKey(M& targetMap, K key, unique_ptr<V>& value)` where you pass both the `unique_ptr` and `targetMap` by reference. With that you won't need to use `std::move` when you call.

Comment: @errantlinguist Okay, and here is a [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=0b3a5d7f59c0fc774f47061dbb186713-41475e255c735859f2b181fd0d057a6f) of your program. The explicit-instantiation of your function template was also causing problems, but I don't know why.